# CXF Client - unexpected XML tag. expected: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope but found: {null}html

Tags: java, web-services, soap, client, cxf

I am trying to call webservice with Apache CXF.

I generated java classes from wsdl file located [here](https://zsmopl.ezdrowie.gov.pl/cxf/zsmopl/ws/?wsdl).

Here is my main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ObslugaKomunikatowService service = new ObslugaKomunikatowService();
    ObslugaKomunikatow client = service.getObslugaKomunikatowPort();
    client.zapiszKomunikatZB(new KomunikatZBMT());
}
```

This code crashes with this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.ws.protocol.soap.MessageCreationException: Couldn't create SOAP message due to exception: unexpected XML tag. expected: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope but found: {null}html
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.encoding.SOAPBindingCodec.decode(SOAPBindingCodec.java:304)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.createResponsePacket(HttpTransportPipe.java:268)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:217)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:130)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:95)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1121)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1035)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1004)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:862)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:448)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:178)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:93)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:77)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:147)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy34.zapiszKomunikatZB(Unknown Source)
    at pl.opencare.zsmoplclient.ZSMOPLClient.main(ZSMOPLClient.java:98)
Caused by: com.sun.xml.internal.ws.streaming.XMLStreamReaderException: unexpected XML tag. expected: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope but found: {null}html
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.streaming.XMLStreamReaderUtil.verifyTag(XMLStreamReaderUtil.java:261)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.decode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:205)
    at com.oracle.webservices.internal.impl.encoding.StreamDecoderImpl.decode(StreamDecoderImpl.java:49)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.decode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:234)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.decode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:151)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.encoding.SOAPBindingCodec.decode(SOAPBindingCodec.java:299)
    ... 15 more
```

There is generated service class:

```
package pl.gov.csioz.zsmopl.ws;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.ws.WebEndpoint;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceClient;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceFeature;
import javax.xml.ws.Service;

/**
 * This class was generated by Apache CXF 3.2.5
 * 2018-07-11T11:38:29.954+02:00
 * Generated source version: 3.2.5
 *
 */
@WebServiceClient(name = "ObslugaKomunikatowService",
                  wsdlLocation = "file:ZSMOPL.wsdl",
                  targetNamespace = "http://csioz.gov.pl/zsmopl/ws/")
public class ObslugaKomunikatowService extends Service {

    public final static URL WSDL_LOCATION;

    public final static QName SERVICE = new QName("http://csioz.gov.pl/zsmopl/ws/", "ObslugaKomunikatowService");
    public final static QName ObslugaKomunikatowPort = new QName("http://csioz.gov.pl/zsmopl/ws/", "ObslugaKomunikatowPort");
    static {
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("file:ZSMOPL.wsdl");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ObslugaKomunikatowService.class.getName())
                .log(java.util.logging.Level.INFO,
                     "Can not initialize the default wsdl from {0}", "file:ZSMOPL.wsdl");
        }
        WSDL_LOCATION = url;
    }

    public ObslugaKomunikatowService(URL wsdlLocation) {
        super(wsdlLocation, SERVICE);
    }

    public ObslugaKomunikatowService(URL wsdlLocation, QName serviceName) {
        super(wsdlLocation, serviceName);
    }

    public ObslugaKomunikatowService() {
        super(WSDL_LOCATION, SERVICE);
    }

    public ObslugaKomunikatowService(WebServiceFeature ... features) {
        super(WSDL_LOCATION, SERVICE, features);
    }

    public ObslugaKomunikatowService(URL wsdlLocation, WebServiceFeature ... features) {
        super(wsdlLocation, SERVICE, features);
    }

    public ObslugaKomunikatowService(URL wsdlLocation, QName serviceName, WebServiceFeature ... features) {
        super(wsdlLocation, serviceName, features);
    }




    /**
     *
     * @return
     *     returns ObslugaKomunikatow
     */
    @WebEndpoint(name = "ObslugaKomunikatowPort")
    public ObslugaKomunikatow getObslugaKomunikatowPort() {
        return super.getPort(ObslugaKomunikatowPort, ObslugaKomunikatow.class);
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param features
     *     A list of {@link javax.xml.ws.WebServiceFeature} to configure on the proxy.  Supported features not in the <code>features</code> parameter will have their default values.
     * @return
     *     returns ObslugaKomunikatow
     */
    @WebEndpoint(name = "ObslugaKomunikatowPort")
    public ObslugaKomunikatow getObslugaKomunikatowPort(WebServiceFeature... features) {
        return super.getPort(ObslugaKomunikatowPort, ObslugaKomunikatow.class, features);
    }

}
```

There is generted port class:

```
package pl.gov.csioz.zsmopl.ws;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebResult;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso;
import javax.xml.ws.RequestWrapper;
import javax.xml.ws.ResponseWrapper;

/**
 * This class was generated by Apache CXF 3.2.5
 * 2018-07-11T11:38:29.942+02:00
 * Generated source version: 3.2.5
 *
 */
@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://csioz.gov.pl/zsmopl/ws/", name = "ObslugaKomunikatow")
@XmlSeeAlso({pl.gov.csioz.zsmopl.ws.obslugakomunikatow.ObjectFactory.class, pl.gov.csioz.zsmopl.mt.ObjectFactory.class})
public interface ObslugaKomunikatow {

    @WebMethod(action = "zapiszKomunikatZB")
    @RequestWrapper(localName = "zapiszKomunikatZB", targetNamespace = "http://csioz.gov.pl/zsmopl/ws/obslugakomunikatow/", className = "pl.gov.csioz.zsmopl.ws.obslugakomunikatow.ZapiszKomunikatZB")
    @ResponseWrapper(localName = "zapiszKomunikatZBResponse", targetNamespace = "http://csioz.gov.pl/zsmopl/ws/obslugakomunikatow/", className = "pl.gov.csioz.zsmopl.ws.obslugakomunikatow.ZapiszKomunikatZBResponse")
    @WebResult(name = "identyfikatorKomunikatu", targetNamespace = "")
    public pl.gov.csioz.zsmopl.mt.IdentyfikatorKomunikatuMT zapiszKomunikatZB(
        @WebParam(name = "komunikatZB", targetNamespace = "")
        pl.gov.csioz.zsmopl.mt.KomunikatZBMT komunikatZB
    ) throws BladTworzeniaIdentyfikatoraKomunikatu, BladDostepnosci;

    @WebMethod(action = "zapiszKomunikatOS")
    @RequestWrapper(localName = "zapiszKomunikatOS", targetNamespace = "http://csioz.gov.pl/zsmopl/ws/obslugakomunikatow/", className = "pl.gov.csioz.zsmopl.ws.obslugakomunikatow.ZapiszKomunikatOS")
    @ResponseWrapper(localName = "zapiszKomunikatOSResponse", targetNamespace = "http://csioz.gov.pl/zsmopl/ws/obslugakomunikatow/", className = "pl.gov.csioz.zsmopl.ws.obslugakomunikatow.ZapiszKomunikatOSResponse")
    @WebResult(name = "identyfikatorKomunikatu", targetNamespace = "")
    public pl.gov.csioz.zsmopl.mt.IdentyfikatorKomunikatuMT zapiszKomunikatOS(
        @WebParam(name = "komunikatOS", targetNamespace = "")
        pl.gov.csioz.zsmopl.mt.KomunikatOSMT komunikatOS
    ) throws BladTworzeniaIdentyfikatoraKomunikatu, BladDostepnosci;

    @WebMethod(action = "zapiszKomunikatPD")
    @RequestWrapper(localName = "zapiszKomunikatPD", targetNamespace = "http://csioz.gov.pl/zsmopl/ws/obslugakomunikatow/", className = "pl.gov.csioz.zsmopl.ws.obslugakomunikatow.ZapiszKomunikatPD")
    @ResponseWrapper(localName = "zapiszKomunikatPDResponse", targetNamespace = "http://csioz.gov.pl/zsmopl/ws/obslugakomunikatow/", className = "pl.gov.csioz.zsmopl.ws.obslugakomunikatow.ZapiszKomunikatPDResponse")
    @WebResult(name = "identyfikatorKomunikatu", targetNamespace = "")
    public pl.gov.csioz.zsmopl.mt.IdentyfikatorKomunikatuMT zapiszKomunikatPD(
        @WebParam(name = "komunikatPD", targetNamespace = "")
        pl.gov.csioz.zsmopl.mt.KomunikatPDMT komunikatPD
    ) throws BladTworzeniaIdentyfikatoraKomunikatu, BladDostepnosci;
}
```

And generated class that I am trying to send:

```
package pl.gov.csioz.zsmopl.mt;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


/**
 * Komunikat zg�oszenia brak�w.
 *             
 * 
 * <p>Java class for KomunikatZBMT complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType name="KomunikatZBMT"&gt;
 *   &lt;complexContent&gt;
 *     &lt;extension base="{http://csioz.gov.pl/zsmopl/mt/}KomunikatMT"&gt;
 *       &lt;sequence&gt;
 *         &lt;element name="idMPDPodmiotuRaportujacego" type="{http://csioz.gov.pl/zsmopl/mt/}IdentyfikatorMPDPodmiotuMT"/&gt;
 *         &lt;element name="komunikatTransakcja" type="{http://csioz.gov.pl/zsmopl/mt/}KomunikatTransakcjaZBMT" maxOccurs="unbounded"/&gt;
 *       &lt;/sequence&gt;
 *     &lt;/extension&gt;
 *   &lt;/complexContent&gt;
 * &lt;/complexType&gt;
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "KomunikatZBMT", propOrder = {
    "idMPDPodmiotuRaportujacego",
    "komunikatTransakcja"
})
public class KomunikatZBMT
    extends KomunikatMT
{

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected IdentyfikatorMPDPodmiotuMT idMPDPodmiotuRaportujacego;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected List<KomunikatTransakcjaZBMT> komunikatTransakcja;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the idMPDPodmiotuRaportujacego property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link IdentyfikatorMPDPodmiotuMT }
     *     
     */
    public IdentyfikatorMPDPodmiotuMT getIdMPDPodmiotuRaportujacego() {
        return idMPDPodmiotuRaportujacego;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the idMPDPodmiotuRaportujacego property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link IdentyfikatorMPDPodmiotuMT }
     *     
     */
    public void setIdMPDPodmiotuRaportujacego(IdentyfikatorMPDPodmiotuMT value) {
        this.idMPDPodmiotuRaportujacego = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the komunikatTransakcja property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * This accessor method returns a reference to the live list,
     * not a snapshot. Therefore any modification you make to the
     * returned list will be present inside the JAXB object.
     * This is why there is not a <CODE>set</CODE> method for the komunikatTransakcja property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * For example, to add a new item, do as follows:
     * <pre>
     *    getKomunikatTransakcja().add(newItem);
     * </pre>
     * 
     * 
     * <p>
     * Objects of the following type(s) are allowed in the list
     * {@link KomunikatTransakcjaZBMT }
     * 
     * 
     */
    public List<KomunikatTransakcjaZBMT> getKomunikatTransakcja() {
        if (komunikatTransakcja == null) {
            komunikatTransakcja = new ArrayList<KomunikatTransakcjaZBMT>();
        }
        return this.komunikatTransakcja;
    }

}
```

Do you know what's causing this exception?

Comment: Did you make any progress with this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps others:
I also got the error message

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.ws.protocol.soap.MessageCreationException: Couldn't create SOAP message due to exception: unexpected XML tag. expected: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope but found: {null}html
```

Or in german:

```
Unerwartetes Tag. Erwartet: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope, gefunden: {null}html
```

I didn't change anything and the request was answered before without any problems until the error occured.

Finally the reason was, that the server was not available and returned an internal server error (500) response and a HTML error message. If you want to see the HTTP errors you can turn HTTP logging on by setting this system properties in your code:

```
System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump", "true")
    System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dump", "true")
    System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump", "true")
    System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dump", "true")
    System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dumpTreshold", "999999")
```